# Discord.py add roles

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to add roles in discord.py but I can't really make it work.

```
@bot.command(brief="Report member")
async def member(ctx):
  if ctx.author.id != 783430063076147210:
    await ctx.send("Mention the member you want to report")

    message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: ctx.author == ctx.author)
    msg = message.content.replace("<","")
    msg = msg.replace(">","")
    msg = msg.replace("@","")
    msg = msg.replace("!","")

    #try:
    msg = int(msg)
    user = bot.get_user(msg)
    await ctx.send('Are you sure you want to report ' + user.mention + "?")

    message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: ctx.author == ctx.author)

    if message.content.lower() == "yes" or message.content.lower() == "y":
      member = ctx.message.author
      role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Reported")
      user = ctx.guild.get_member(msg)
      await bot.add_roles(user, role)
      await ctx.send(user.mention + " was reported by " + member.mention + ".")
    else:
      await ctx.send("User was not reported!")
    #except:
      await ctx.send("Oops! That was not a user!")
```

I'm getting an `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'`, and the same with the other way

```
await user.add_roles(role)
```

returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'`

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you know this was asked elsewhere and answered then can you please state in the question why this is a unique question that should not be closed as a duplicate? Just because you say it doesn't work for you doesn't mean people will take time. Quite a few users would quickly close as a duplicate with the idea being you just have to interpret the existing answers. I'm not going to flag as a duplicate but just in case I recommend you provide reasons in the question as to how this is unique and worthy of not being a duplicate. Good luck

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: yup! It's enabled at the beginning of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways of making this work:

1.

```
@bot.command()
async def role(ctx, member:commands.MemberConverter, role:commands.RoleConverter):
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

^^ This method uses a role converter that accepts role ID, name, or mention.
I also use `commands.MemberConverter` because it accepts more methods of referencing a user than `discord.Member`, and the same thing for `discord.Role`.

2.

```
@bot.command()
async def role(ctx, member:commands.MemberConverter, role):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

^^ This method uses `discord.utils.get` to get a guild role.  From my knowledge, it only accepts role names and not role IDs or mentions.

Answer (score 0):

`bot.get_user()` will return a `User` object, to which you cannot add roles, as no guild is specified. You could do `ctx.guild.get_member(id)` to get the `Member` object then add roles to that, but you'd be better of getting the member from the `mentions` attribute of a `Message`. Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=mentions#discord.Message.mentions

Comment: Notice that the `user` variable is a `member` type. It might be confusing

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def role(ctx):
    test = ctx.author
    role = discord.utils.get(test.guild.roles, name="Name")
    if role in test.roles:
        await ctx.send("you already have a role")
    else:
        await test.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
await bot.add_roles(user, role)
```

needs to be replaced by

```
await user.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score -1):

these are my addrole and remouverole commands:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def addrole(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : discord.Role):
    await member.add_roles(role) 
    await ctx.send(f"{role} is added to {member}.")

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def removerole(ctx, member : discord.Member, role : discord.Role):
    await member.remove_roles(role) 
    await ctx.send(f"{role} is removed from {member}.")
```